# Is it "I'm new to NYC" or "I'm new in NYC"?

Tags: prepositions

As the title of my question suggests, I want to know whether we can say both expressions are correct, or if one of them is wrong.  Which phrase is wrong, and why?

> I'm new **to** NYC.
>
> I'm new **in** NYC.

I'm not a native speaker but I tended to use "I'm new to NYC" without a second thought. But a friend of mine told me it was wrong. So now I'm baffled between the two examples. I can't be 100% sure when it comes to such expressions because, as I said, English is not my mother tongue.

Comment: Take a look at this [question](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/278152/which-preposition-for-are-you-new-to-at-in-school).

Comment: I checked it @Rathony, however I am not satisfied with the answers. They were all thumbed down. And as for to/in school, it might be heard more commonly but about cities, it is a rare case using "to" I guess...

Comment: So you don't think "I'm new to the City" would ever be used?

Comment: I'm not a native speaker but I tended to use "I'm new to NYC" without even second-thinking. But another friend of mine said it was wrong. So now I'm baffled between the two examples. I know it is a bit simple and you would lynch me for that, but I can't be 100% sure when it comes to such expressions in English as I said, it is not my mother tongue. :(

Comment: As it happens, [Cambridge Dictionaries](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/new) specifically defines *to be new **to** [something]* (not ​yet ​familiar or ​experienced). But their example usages are *to be new to the ​area* and *She's new to the ​job so you can't ​expect her to ​know everything ​yet*, where I'd be quite happy with ***in*** for either context, or ***at*** for the second, so I think it's essentially just a matter of opinion. In short, there is no "right" answer.

Comment: Oh, great! So I was not wrong. Thanks for the answer!

Comment: I don't have a usage guide to back this up, but my sense is that *new to* is more appropriate to locations (cities, towns, countries, etc.), while *new in* is more appropriate to abstract entities which are not just a geographical location (*new in this job*, *in this position*, *in this club*, etc.), though you'll frequently hear *to* used for these latter abstract uses as well. I think there's also a difference: *new to* can imply "first time" AND temporarily visiting a location, whereas *new in* would sound odd to me expressing that sense (if *in* the city you are staying awhile).

Comment: We don't know the context for what you and your friend were saying, but 'in' sounds wrong to me in most contexts.

Answer (score -1):

One could be "new in NY", as in recently moved there and yet not be "new to NY" because one had extensively visited on previous occasions.  "new TO" would tend to indicate that one does not have previous knowledge of, while "new IN" would mean recently moved to.